# Running parallel HTTP Requests in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, asynchronous, meteor

Let's say I have a collection of documents that need to be updated from an external API. On the client, I fetch these docs and then delegate the call to the API on the Server in a Meteor method

I.e.

```
//on client
const docs = Docs.find().fetch();
for (let doc of docs) {
  //Delegate to Server to handle actual request to external API and updating to DB
  Meteor.call('updateFromExternalAPI', doc);
}
```

I'm aware this is not efficient and I'd like to run these requests in parallel. I've used `Promises.all()` before and understand there's probably a myriad of ways to do this in standard JS and other frameworks. But, what's the desired pattern for doing things like this in Meteor? Will I have to rely on other npm packages?

Any contemporary blogs, tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `Meteor.call` not async (and therefore parallel) as it is? You're going to have to loop through the `docs` at least once to make the calls, whether it's in your code or in some utility.

Answer (score 4):

> I'd like to run these requests in parallel

Without seeing your server code, I guess the only thing lacking to make the code fully parallel is [`this.unblock()`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#DDPCommon-MethodInvocation-unblock) at the beginning of the `updateFromExternalAPI` method. This would allow the next method to be called immediately, instead of waiting for the previous method call to return.

> what's the desired pattern for doing things like this in Meteor?

Ideally, you would edit `updateFromExternalAPI` (or make a similar method) to take all `docs` at the same time and do the iteration itself.

Even better, that method would `.fetch()` the data instead of receiving the complete docs from the client. The server should already have access to those anyway. If necessary, the server could filter based on criteria sent from the client (e.g. a list of `_id`s).

Does that help?